# AWS SES, email attachment sends base64 string instead converting into DOCX format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

*Requirement*

What I am trying to do is, First I will download a document from S3 Bucket, Then sending that document through SES, sendRawEmail method as attachment with the file downloaded from S3.

*What I Did till Now*

I have downloaded the file from S3, I can send a mail with attachment. It reaches the destination as expected(form.docx)

*Error*

When I am sending the attachment, I have to append the base64 (which is the attachment)String in the formdata. I am attaching the string. But When I download the attachment. There I can see, inside the form.docx, there is converted base64 string inside the attachment. It is not as expected. I should see tables and some fill in the blanks kind of thing. But here it is a very big base64 string

*Code*

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3= new AWS.S3();
let ses = new AWS.SES();
exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const valueFromBucket = await S3.getObject({Bucket: '*******', Key: 'form.docx'}).promise();
    var buffer = valueFromBucket.Body.toString('base64');
    var message = '<html><body ><div> This is a test Message</div></body></html>';
    var fromEmail = '******@gmail.com';
    var toEmail = '*******@gmail.com';
    var ses_mail = "From: 'Email' <" + fromEmail + ">\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + toEmail + "\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: Subject Email\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + message+"\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: application/msword\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"form.docx\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"
    ses_mail = ses_mail + buffer + "\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart--";

    var params = {
        RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail)},
        Destinations: [ "*******@gmail.com" ],
        Source: "'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + fromEmail + ">'"
    };
    const sendPromise = await new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
    .sendRawEmail(params)
    .promise();
    return{
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(sendPromise)
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
      body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Any help or suggestions much appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1) Do not use simple strings for your `boundary`. 2) Two newlines (remove one) `"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"form.docx\"\n\n";`

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh Man, Thanks a lot that worked.

Comment: please post that as an answer

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you please look into this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635500/docx-document-serverless-s3-error-while-putobject-method , it is similar but I couldn't figure it out.  Any help much appreciated

Comment: A minor improvement - `new Buffer(string)` is now deprecated, therefore the code where it is used could be replaced with `Buffer.from(string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code has two newlines for one of your section part headers.

Change this line of code:

```
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
```

to this:

```
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n";
```